# Create inheritance class and print out data from the parent class array

Tags: java, arrays, class, oop, inheritance

So i have to create a class and  methods for getting userinput and one for printing them out

After i printed out the numbers. Im supposed to  make inherited class and print out the same numbers but with their indexes,
How can i get the numbers data from the first class?

```
public class Main {

    public  static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here

        OriginalMethod firstoutput = new OriginalMethod();
        firstoutput.OriginalMethod();
        firstoutput.out();
        overki newki = new overki();
        newki.out();


    }
    static class OriginalMethod {
        public int []tomb = new  int[3];
       public void  OriginalMethod(){



           for(int i = 0; i<3;i++)
           {
               Scanner beolvas = new Scanner(System.in);
               System.out.println("Enter the "+(i+1)+".number");
               tomb[i] = beolvas.nextInt();

           }

       }

       public void out()
       {

           for(int i = 0; i<3;i++)
           {
               System.out.print(tomb[i]+" ");

           }
       }

    }
    static class overki extends OriginalMethod {
        @Override
        public void out()
    
        {
            System.out.println();
            for(int i = 0; i<3;i++)
            {
                System.out.println(i+". "+tomb[i]);
    
            }
    
    
        }
    
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really the way I learned to code classes in Java (I learned about creating new Java classes inside the project's package rather than directly creating numerous classes inside the *Main Class*). That would allow you to create constructors, and then easily pass variables by using the ***super*** keyword, or even through some ***getter-setters***. However, for the code you provided, the easiest solution I found was this :

```
public class Main {

    public  static void main(String[] args) {
        int[]tomb;
        OriginalMethod firstoutput = new OriginalMethod();
        tomb = firstoutput.OriginalMethod();
        firstoutput.out(tomb);
        overki newki = new overki();
        newki.out(tomb);
    }

    static class OriginalMethod {
        public int[]  OriginalMethod(){
            int []tomb = new int[3];
            for(int i = 0; i<3;i++)
            {
                Scanner beolvas = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Enter the "+(i+1)+".number");
                tomb[i] = beolvas.nextInt();
            }
            return tomb;
        }

        public void out(int[]tomb)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i<3;i++)
            {
                System.out.print(tomb[i]+" ");
            }
        }
    }

    static class overki extends OriginalMethod {
        @Override
        public void out(int[]tomb)
        {
            System.out.println();
            for(int i = 0; i<3;i++)
            {
                System.out.println(i+". "+tomb[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Allow me to explain what I changed. First off, I moved the `int[]tomb` variable out of the `OriginalMethod` class and into the *Main*. Then, I changed the `OriginalMethod` in order for it to return an int array. Therefore, you can easily "export" your array out of your `OriginalMethod` from the main by writing `tomb = firstoutput.OriginalMethod()`. From there, you simply have to change your `out` methods so that they both receive this array we created in the *Main* (since the second `out()` method is an ***Override***, it is **absolutely necessary** that they both receive the **same** thing in their parameters).

And well, it does the trick. Now, is it perfect? Probably not. As I said, I probably would've used ***getter-setters*** had I done this myself, but starting with your original code, this is the easiest solution I found!

Comment: First of all! I would like to say big thanks, its amazing how delatiled your comment is, it help me a lot.!
Secondly , We just started to learn about opp , getters and setters , inhertience m its really confusing :D comments like this truly helps me a lot

Comment: Just for the sake of it , i did it with getter and setters, created  a class with override, it is bit more diffucult but i can understand why its it better

Comment: Happy to hear you were able to make it better. Creating new classes is a little more lenghty (but really not that much), but it makes the code much more readable and just much better. In fact, it's the way classes are supposed to be made in a Java program. Best of luck in your learning!

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the concept of class and instance (an object) mixed up.

It appears that you require only one instance - that of the subclass.

```
overki newki = new overki();
newki.OriginalMethod();
newki.out();
newki.out();
```

It also looks like the method `OriginalMethod` should be a constructor - the spurious `void` is a common mistake. So change:

```
public void  OriginalMethod(){
```

to:

```
public OriginalMethod() {
```

and remove the line:

```
newki.OriginalMethod();
```